# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set a property of my .ascx controls from an .aspx using that control.

So in one of my **.aspx** which has this control in it, I have the following code trying to set the ItemsList property of my embedded .ascx:

```
Item item = GetItem(itemID);
myUsercontrol.ItemList = new List<Item>().Add(item);
```

The property in the .ascx that I'm trying to set looks like this:

```
public List<Item> ItemsList
{
   get { return this.itemsList; }
   set { this.itemsList = value; }
}
```

**Error**: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

So I don't get where it's getting void as part of the property?...weird.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do that because the Add function returns void, not a reference to the list. You can do this:

```
mycontrol.ItemList = new List<Item>();
mycontrol.ItemList.Add(item);
```

or use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
mycontrol.ItemList = new List<Item> { item };
```

Comment: I created a new instance of the list with the new keyword, why would Add have anything to do with reutrning the NEW instance that I already specified?  I'm just adding content to the list array

Comment: @cofffeeaddict: You are trying to set a property which expects an instance of the list. The `Add` method is void.

Comment: I gave it an instance...with new List<Item>..the new keyword.

Comment: I would assume the way I did this was new created a new instance and then I'm simply appending an add which adds the item to the new instance of List<Item>

Comment: @coffeeaddict: You are expecting kind of a fluent interface, which is not the case with `List<T>.Add`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ItemListt.ItemList = new List<Item>().Add(item);
```

Does `Add` method return an instance of a list based class?

EDIT: No, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) for documentation on `List<T>.Add`

EDIT2: Try writing this piece of code & see what is the return value of `Add` method.

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
var modifiedList = items.Add(myItem);
```

You will see that, the code should fail at `Add` because it returns `void`.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I refreshed the page several times. But I can't see any changes in the code. The problem still lies with your usage of `Add` method which returns a void. Use a collection initializer instead. `new List<Item>() {item};` (I hope this syntax is right).

Answer (score 1):

After creating the `List<Item>` you're immediately calling Add on it, which is a method returning void. This cannot be converted to the type of ItemList.ItemList.

You should do this instead:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(item);
ItemList.ItemList = list;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new List<Item>().Add(item);
```

This line returns void.

Try:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(item);
ItemListt.ItemList = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as `ItemList` is instantiated on your usercontrol, you can just do `UserControl.ItemList.Add(item)`

Comment: Why does ItemList need to be instantiated anywhere but where I've already instantiated it. I used the new keyword right there, it's already an instance!

Comment: correct, but the List<T>.Add() method has a void return type, so you can't assign it mycontrol.ItemList().  You would have to either insantiate it separately on another line, or use a collection initializer.  My answer applies if you've already performed the instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

The Add method doesn't return a reference to the list. You have to do this in two steps:

```
ItemListt.ItemList = new List<Item>();
ItemListt.ItemList.Add(item);
```

Alternatively use a local variable to hold the reference before you put it in the property:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(item);
ItemListt.ItemList = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who might come here from Googling the error:

Sometimes it's because you didn't finish writing a line but it compiles anyway and the error only shows up on the next line which can be confusing/misleading if you don't pay attention. Eg:

```
var foo = 33;
var bar = 

// Note that I never finished the assignation (got distracted, saved and it compiled)
//
// Some unrelated code returning "void" (another example would be List.Add)
await SomethingAsync(); // -> Error shows up here instead
```

Might save some of you all some headache trying to figure why "awaiting on my function" raises a "Cannot convert void to X", when really it's not the actual issue.