# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

I am facing this but unable to solve it.This are from List. Having the problem at 
`AddOnTriggerItems = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowItem => new AddOnTriggerItem()`

```
ProjectA.TEST.BE.AddOn addOn = new ProjectA.TEST.BE.AddOn()
{    
    AddCode = addCode,          
    CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now,
    AddOnTriggers = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(row => new AddOnTrigger()
    {
        AddOnTriggerItems = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowItem => new AddOnTriggerItem()
        {
            ProductTypeID = gvTriggerProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString(),
            ProductCode = gvTriggerProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(),     
            CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
            ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now
        }).ToList(),
        ActiveStatus = 1,
        CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now
    }).ToList(),
    AddOnProducts = gvAddOnProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowAddOnProducts => new AddOnProduct()
    {
        ProductTypeID = gvAddOnProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(), 
        ProductCode = gvAddOnProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(),   
        CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now,
        AddOnProductAllotments = addOnProductAllotmentSession.Where(p => (p.ProductID == (Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)rowAddOnProducts.FindControl("ProductID")).Value)))).ToList(),      
    }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: in class AddOnProduct, is ProductTypeID an integer or a string? there is a similar error posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407348/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-ui-webcontrols-label-to-type-system

Comment: Error thrown is not at the ProdutTypeID. It is at AddOnTriggerItems = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowItem => new AddOnTriggerItem()    AddOnTrigger is the parent, while AddOnTriggerItems is the child. It is 1 to many relationship. Not sure am I writring correctly for this as while.

Comment: Then check ProductTypeID in class AddOnTriggerItem.

Comment: I'd put it as like that. consider that 1 as string for the producttypeID. I need to masked that info. it is initially a byte and the value is convert to byte. in actual it is Convert.ToByte((((HiddenField)rowItem.FindControl("hfNewProductID")).Value).Split('_')[0]),

Comment: assuming gvTriggerProduct is a GridView, why do you cast its rows as GridViewRow? they should already be rows.

Comment: how should i wrote this? kind of new to this. thx,,,,

Comment: For starter try removing ".Cast<GridViewRow>()". My guess is GridViewRow does not support Cast operation because the class does not implement IConvertible interface. Also we need to make sure that gvTriggerProduct is actually a GridView.

Comment: I'd removed but giving me direct error. I was referring this to a sample that work. The difference is that: Mine has extra layer of AddOnTriggers = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(row => new AddOnTrigger()
I don't know how to check on this part. as AddOnproduct (Parent) refer to those data in textboxes. AddOnTriggers(at table hierarchy which only keep those at the code) child of AddOnProduct. While AddOnTriggersItem( coming from Gridview) child of AddOnTriggers

Comment: Note: the problem can be anywhere within the statement that starts in the error line. If the statement is spanning multiple lines, the error may still be reported for the first line. So don't just focus on `AddOnTriggerItems = [...]` but also on anything until `}).ToList(),`

Answer (score -1):

Thx to grek and derloopkat.
Grek's hint: the problem can be anywhere within the statement that starts in the error line

There are 3 parts that I changed.

1. I cannot have 2 gvTriggerProduct.
2. One part in my existing code(not here). Missing ".Value". Grek's hint       Convert.ToByte(((DropDownList)rowItem.FindControl("ddlMinTriggerQuantity")).SelectedItem
3. [Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868348/error-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-void-to-system-collections-generic-list)

   ```
    List<AddOnTrigger> triggerlist = new List<AddOnTrigger>();
   triggerList.Add(new AddOnTrigger
   {
    AddOnTriggerItems = gvTriggerProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowItem => new AddOnTriggerItem()
   {
       ProductTypeID = gvTriggerProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString(),
       ProductCode = gvTriggerProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(),     
       CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
       ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now
   }).ToList(),
   ActiveStatus = 1,
   CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
   ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now}
   });

   ProjectA.TEST.BE.AddOn addOn = new ProjectA.TEST.BE.AddOn()
   { 
      AddCode = addCode,          
      CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
      ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now,
      AddOnTriggers = triggerlist
      AddOnProducts = gvAddOnProduct.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Select(rowAddOnProducts => new AddOnProduct()
      {
         ProductTypeID =    gvAddOnProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(),    
         ProductCode = gvAddOnProduct.Rows[rowItem.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(), 
         CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
         ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now,
         AddOnProductAllotments = addOnProductAllotmentSession.Where(p => (p.ProductID == (Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)rowAddOnProducts.FindControl("ProductID")).Value )))).ToList(),      
   }).ToList()

   };
   ```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the answer? Its not very clear and **IF** the problem was related to some code that was not part of your question, then better delete the question, because the answer will not help others.